# Robot moves through ground plane

Tags: collision

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

I have two ground planes in my simulation, one with 0 rpy and the other pitching by 30 degrees. The aim is to have a robot move along the flat plain and then move along the pitched plane.

The problem is that my robot simply moves though the second plane instead of moving along it.

The world file definition is:

```
<sdf version='1.6'>
  <world name='default'>
    <light name='sun' type='directional'>
      <cast_shadows>1</cast_shadows>
      <pose frame=''>0 0 10 0 -0 0</pose>
      <diffuse>0.8 0.8 0.8 1</diffuse>
      <specular>0.1 0.1 0.1 1</specular>
      <attenuation>
        <range>1000</range>
        <constant>0.9</constant>
        <linear>0.01</linear>
        <quadratic>0.001</quadratic>
      </attenuation>
      <direction>-0.5 0.5 -1</direction>
    </light>
    <model name='ground_plane'>
      <static>1</static>
      <link name='link'>
        <collision name='collision'>
          <geometry>
            <plane>
              <normal>0 0 1</normal>
              <size>100 100</size>
            </plane>
          </geometry>
          <surface>
            <friction>
              <ode>
                <mu>100</mu>
                <mu2>50</mu2>
              </ode>
              <torsional>
                <ode/>
              </torsional>
            </friction>
            <contact>
              <ode/>
            </contact>
            <bounce/>
          </surface>
          <max_contacts>10</max_contacts>
        </collision>
        <visual name='visual'>
          <cast_shadows>0</cast_shadows>
          <geometry>
            <plane>
              <normal>0 0 1</normal>
              <size>100 100</size>
            </plane>
          </geometry>
          <material>
            <script>
              <uri>file://media/materials/scripts/gazebo.material</uri>
              <name>Gazebo/Grey</name>
            </script>
          </material>
        </visual>
        <self_collide>0</self_collide>
        <kinematic>0</kinematic>
        <gravity>1</gravity>
      </link>
    </model>
    <gravity>0 0 -9.8</gravity>
    <magnetic_field>6e-06 2.3e-05 -4.2e-05</magnetic_field>
    <atmosphere type='adiabatic'/>
    <physics name='default_physics' default='0' type='ode'>
      <max_step_size>0.001</max_step_size>
      <real_time_factor>1</real_time_factor>
      <real_time_update_rate>1000</real_time_update_rate>
    </physics>
    <scene>
      <ambient>0.4 0.4 0.4 1</ambient>
      <background>0.7 0.7 0.7 1</background>
      <shadows>1</shadows>
    </scene>
    <spherical_coordinates>
      <surface_model>EARTH_WGS84</surface_model>
      <latitude_deg>0</latitude_deg>
      <longitude_deg>0</longitude_deg>
      <elevation>0</elevation>
      <heading_deg>0</heading_deg>
    </spherical_coordinates>
    <model name='ground_plane_0'>
      <static>1</static>
      <link name='link'>
        <collision name='collision'>
          <geometry>
            <plane>
              <normal>0 0 1</normal>
              <size>100 100</size>
            </plane>
          </geometry>
          <surface>
            <friction>
              <ode>
                <mu>100</mu>
                <mu2>50</mu2>
              </ode>
              <torsional>
                <ode/>
              </torsional>
            </friction>
            <contact>
              <ode/>
            </contact>
            <bounce/>
          </surface>
          <max_contacts>10</max_contacts>
        </collision>
        <visual name='visual'>
          <cast_shadows>0</cast_shadows>
          <geometry>
            <plane>
              <normal>0 0 1</normal>
              <size>100 100</size>
            </plane>
          </geometry>
          <material>
            <script>
              <uri>file://media/materials/scripts/gazebo.material</uri>
              <name>Gazebo/Grey</name>
            </script>
          </material>
        </visual>
        <self_collide>0</self_collide>
        <kinematic>0</kinematic>
        <gravity>1</gravity>
      </link>
      <pose frame=''>19.5012 -0.03334 0 0 -0.523599 0</pose>
        <scale>1 1 1</scale>
        <link name='link'>
          <pose frame=''>19.5012 -0.03334 0 0 -0.523599 0</pose>
          <velocity>0 0 0 0 -0 0</velocity>
          <acceleration>0 0 0 0 -0 0</acceleration>
          <wrench>0 0 0 0 -0 0</wrench>
        </link>
    </model>
    <state world_name='default'>
      <sim_time>68 495000000</sim_time>
      <real_time>68 588233894</real_time>
      <wall_time>1494140513 740272417</wall_time>
      <iterations>68495</iterations>
      <model name='ground_plane'>
        <pose frame=''>0 0 0 0 -0 0</pose>
        <scale>1 1 1</scale>
        <link name='link'>
          <pose frame=''>0 0 0 0 -0 0</pose>
          <velocity>0 0 0 0 -0 0</velocity>
          <acceleration>0 0 0 0 -0 0</acceleration>
          <wrench>0 0 0 0 -0 0</wrench>
        </link>
      </model>
      <light name='sun'>
        <pose frame=''>0 0 10 0 -0 0</pose>
      </light>
    </state>
    <gui fullscreen='0'>
      <camera name='user_camera'>
        <pose frame=''>28.2196 -145.268 132.345 0 0.851643 1.5882</pose>
        <view_controller>orbit</view_controller>
        <projection_type>perspective</projection_type>
      </camera>
    </gui>
  </world>
</sdf>
```

I'm sure I'm just missing a simple collision property but I haven't been able to figure it out yet.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/16097/robot-moves-through-ground-plane/) by [janindu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3224/janindu/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-05-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

This looks like a bug. I've reported it [here](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issues/2274/plane-geometry-not-matching-gui)

---

Originally posted by [Peter Mitrano](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1068/peter-mitrano/) with karma: 768 on 2017-05-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0